# git integration in vscode stops working after adding remote folder to workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode does not show repository at local path while using remote connection. I'm using "Remote SSH" from M$.

Here is my workspace:

```
{
"folders": [
    {
        "path": "/local/path/to/project-with-git-repo"
    },
    {
        "uri": "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+10.11.12.13/remote/path"
    }
],
"remoteAuthority": "ssh-remote+10.11.12.13",
"settings": {}
}
```

After removing "remoteAuthority" local repository becomes visible. Any ideas how to enable git integration for local repo while using remote connection?